# Dangerous script Will it work?

Tags: c, file-io, replace

I am trying to create a function that opens a text file and read its content char-by-char to the end and when the function encounter a match of a specific string, it clears the line where the string was. (or at least replace each of the characters with a null character).

Here is what i have:

```
void clear_blocker ()
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("debug_output.txt", "r+"); // opens a file to read and update
    char handle [] = // the string to compare from
    "Critical: Unexpected Crash Event. Application forced to terminate/task killed";
    char buff[] = // allocating the buff statically. lazy counting.
    "Critical: Unexpected Crash Event. Application forced to terminate/task killed+";
    long cur, n=0, iter;

    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET); // secure rewinding
    *buff = NULL; // emptying buff content
    for( ; cur != EOF; cur=fgetc(fp)) // loop trough the file, obtaining each char
    {
        n++; // counter
        if(strlen(buff) <= strlen(handle))  buff[n] = cur; // copying strings (size-limited)
        else { *buff = NULL; n = 0; } // restarts content of buff to obtain next
        if(!strcmp(buff, handle)) // if the content matches the string
        {
            for(iter = ftell(fp)-strlen(handle); iter<ftell(fp); iter++) // iter indicates the start of the string in the file and it increments to the end
            {
                fseek(fp, iter, SEEK_SET); // using the iter to set the position indicator
                fputc(NULL, fp); // ..and put NULL there
            }
            break; // breaks out the loop
        }
    }

}
```

The problem i have with my code is that it says i am overflowing the array `buff` on that line:

```
if(strlen(buff) <= strlen(handle))  buff[n] = cur;
```

And i am sure it has more then this as a problem.

Comment: Look up `fgets()` and `strstr()`; they will make it much easier to solve the problem than character-by-character input.  The code is inscrutable — or, at the least, the purpose of the inner loop is far from obvious and it is not clear what is intended to happen, but I'd lay odds it doesn't do what is intended.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `fgets` returns only one line. Do i comment each of the line with why i have done it?

Comment: Yes: `fgets()` only reads one line at a time.  That's OK; you only want to destroy one line at a time, and it is easier to identify lines when the input function does it for you than when you do it yourself ad hoc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler shall i comment each of the lines to make it more clear?

Comment: Well written code seldom needs comments at a line-by-line level. The inner `for` loop seeks to some offset relative to the current position, outputs a character (thereby changing the position to one place after the value in `iter`), increments `iter`, and compares the value with `ftell(fp)`. Since these are now equal, the loop terminates after the first iteraction. That probably wasn't what you intended to do. … _All that needs to be qualified with_ I think _because I've not run the code_. It is at best a very unusual way of writing code, and unusual often means 'bug-prone' even if not buggy.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Done editing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59973/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-edenia).

Answer (score -1):

I wrote some `strstr` function, since i don't have it enabled. I hope it is similar to the real one and it will work out.

```
char* strstrr ( char *str1, char *str2 )
{
    int i
    char* left = malloc(strlen(str1)+strlen(str2)+1);

    for(i=0; i<strlen(str1); i++)
    {
        strcpy(left, str2);
        strcat(left, &str1[i+strlen(str2)]);

        if(!strcmp(&str1[i], left)) { return &str1[i]; }
    }
    free(left);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: This causes a memory leak.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY And how exactly?

Comment: You need to release the `left` before return. Also, It seems better to use `strncmp` or `memcmp` is as easy.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY What do  you mean by release the `left` before return? Where is it released now? The function does its job anyway.. i don't think it matters.

Comment: why would i release it before that?